# Find <a> tags between two <i> tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html

I'm using python and beautifulsoup. I have a html page which looks like this:

```
<i>Hello<\i>
<a href="www.google.com"> Google <\a>
<i>Bye<\i>
<a href="www.google.com"> Google2 <\a>
<i>Hello<\i>
<a href="www.google.com"> Google3 <\a>
<i>Bye<\i>
```

I would like to get all the "a" tags text(which I know how to do, I just don't know how to get to them) between the Hello and Bye tags but not between the Bye and Hello tags. Would it be possible with beautiful soup and python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I corrected your HTML slightly. (Notice that the backslashes should be slashes.)

To do this, first find the 'Hello' strings. Call one of these strings `s` in the for-loop. Then what you want is `s.findParent().findNextSibling()`.

I display `s`, `s.findParent()` and `s.findParent().findNextSibling()` to show you how I went about constructing what you needed from these strings.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> HTML = '''\
... <i>Hello</i>
... <a href="www.google.com"> Google </a>
... <i>Bye</i>
... <a href="www.google.com"> Google2 </a>
... <i>Hello</i>
... <a href="www.google.com"> Google3 </a>
... <i>Bye</i>
... '''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> for s in soup.find_all(string='Hello'):
...     s, s.findParent(), s.findParent().findNextSibling()
...     
('Hello', <i>Hello</i>, <a href="www.google.com"> Google </a>)
('Hello', <i>Hello</i>, <a href="www.google.com"> Google3 </a>)
```

Comment: Indeed my HTML code was wrong, thank you for correcting it. However what if I wanted to keep calling findNextSibling() until it returned me the right tag, how would I go about that? Would I be able to use the return value of findNextSibling() in a while loop, and then just call s.findNextSibling() and expect it to turn the next tag in the html code?

Comment: If you were to use `s.findNextSibling()` repeatedly you would get the same thing each time! Instead, your loop would have to be something like `t=s.findNextSibling();while <something>;t=t.find.NextSibling();<do something with t>`.

Comment: I'm going to presume to offer you a tip. It's a thousand times easier to build code like this in a REPL environment. I hesitate to recommend *any* because I disagree with so many choices that others offer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mix of BeautifulSoup and regex. Here regex is used to grab everything between the limit tags, then BeautifulSoup is used to extract the anchor tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

excerpts = re.findall(r'<i>Hello<\\i>(.*?)<i>Bye<\\i>', html, re.DOTALL)

for e in excerpts:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(e)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        print(link)
```

Output:

```
<a href="www.google.com"> Google </a>
<a href="www.google.com"> Google3 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `re` module. Reference see [Regular Expression Howto for py2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

```
str_tags = """
<i>Hello<\i>
<a href="www.google.com"> Google <\a>
<i>Bye<\i>
<a href="www.google.com"> Google2 <\a>
<i>Hello<\i>
<a href="www.google.com"> Google3 <\a>
<i>Bye<\i>
"""

import re
str_re = re.compile(r".*Hello.*\s<a[^>]*>([\w\s]+)<\a>\s<i>Bye")
content_lst = str_re.findall(str_tags)
if content_lst:
    print(content_lst)
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Output

> [' Google ', ' Google3 ']

Note this method depends strongly on what your html looks like. 
For explanation about the above code, please also refer to the first link.

Comment: Unfortunally the example was only an example of what it looked like. Because im web scraping a page, it might not always yeld the same results